# freq table for multiple variables in r

Tags: r, crosstab

I would like to crosstab the items variable vs cat as a frequency table.

```
df1 <- data.frame(cat =   c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  item1 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                  item2 = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0),
                  item3 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1))

> table(df1$cat, df1$item1)
   
    0 1
  1 3 1
  2 3 2
  3 3 2
  4 2 2
```

Is there a way to print all the items variables freq table by cat together?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you think this output should look like, explicitly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List <- list()
for(i in 2:dim(df1)[2])
{
  List[[i-1]] <- table(df1$cat, df1[,i])
}

[[1]]
   
    0 1
  1 3 1
  2 3 2
  3 3 2
  4 2 2

[[2]]
   
    0 1
  1 1 3
  2 3 2
  3 2 3
  4 3 1

[[3]]
   
    0 1
  1 3 1
  2 3 2
  3 2 3
  4 2 2
```

Comment: `lapply(df1[,-1], function(z) table(df1[,1], z))`?

Comment: Hi @Duck, I ran into this error in the complete data `Error in table(df1$cat, df1[, i]) : 
  all arguments must have the same length`. Some categories might have `NA` information for some items. Is there a way to bypass that? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @amisos55 Hi! Try adding `exclude = NULL` inside `table` this could help.

Comment: The dataframe was `"spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame" `. so I specified the dataframe with `df1 <- as.dataframe(df1)`. now ti works great. thanks

Comment: @amisos55 Great you are `R` master and what you did is valid :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick solution in base-R

```
aggregate(.~ cat, df1, table)

  cat item1.0 item1.1 item2.0 item2.1 item3.0 item3.1
1   1       3       1       1       3       3       1
2   2       3       2       3       2       3       2
3   3       3       2       2       3       2       3
4   4       2       2       3       1       2       2
```

Comment: Plus 1, but watch out for the structure of the object created by this. If you want a regular `data.frame`, you'd want something like `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(.~ cat, df1, table))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tally()` to get the frequency for every combination of groups.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(cat = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  item1 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                  item2 = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0),
                  item3 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)) 

df1 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor) %>% 
  group_by(cat, item1, item2, item3, .drop=F) %>% 
  tally()
```

First convert your variables to factors then you can then use `group_by(, .drop=F) %>% tally()` to tally all of your variables, including all groupings with zero frequencies. Remove `.drop=F` to remove all zero frequencies.

```
   cat item1 item2 item3 n
1    1     0     0     0 0
2    1     0     0     1 0
3    1     0     1     0 3
4    1     0     1     1 0
5    1     1     0     0 0
6    1     1     0     1 1
7    1     1     1     0 0
8    1     1     1     1 0
9    2     0     0     0 1
10   2     0     0     1 1
11   2     0     1     0 1
12   2     0     1     1 0
13   2     1     0     0 0
14   2     1     0     1 1
15   2     1     1     0 1
16   2     1     1     1 0
17   3     0     0     0 0
18   3     0     0     1 0
19   3     0     1     0 1
20   3     0     1     1 2
21   3     1     0     0 1
22   3     1     0     1 1
23   3     1     1     0 0
24   3     1     1     1 0
25   4     0     0     0 0
26   4     0     0     1 1
27   4     0     1     0 1
28   4     0     1     1 0
29   4     1     0     0 1
30   4     1     0     1 1
31   4     1     1     0 0
32   4     1     1     1 0
```

Alternatively, if that is too unwieldy, you can also try `table1()` from `library(table1)`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(table1)
df1 <- data.frame(cat = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  item1 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                  item2 = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0),
                  item3 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)) 

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor)

table1(~ item1 + item2 + item3 | cat, data=df1)
```

To get a table of the frequencies and percentages. The top row is your `cat` variable.

[image: table1 table]

`table1()` is really great for generating HTML frequency tables. Highly recommend. You can do lots of formatting and labels to make tables presentable. [Here is a tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using `ftable` and `stack` from base R:

```
x <- ftable(cbind(cat = df1[, 1], stack(df1[-1])), row.vars = 1, col.vars = c(3, 2))
x
#     ind    item1   item2   item3  
#     values     0 1     0 1     0 1
# cat                               
# 1              3 1     1 3     3 1
# 2              3 2     3 2     3 2
# 3              3 2     2 3     2 3
# 4              2 2     3 1     2 2
```

One (debatable) downside of this approach is that the default `data.table` or `data.frame` methods for converting `ftables` to more usable objects will convert the output to a long format. But, you can [grab `SOfun`](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/) and use `ftable2dt` if you want to keep the wide format.

```
library(SOfun)
ftable2dt(x)
#    cat item1_0 item1_1 item2_0 item2_1 item3_0 item3_1
# 1:   1       3       1       1       3       3       1
# 2:   2       3       2       3       2       3       2
# 3:   3       3       2       2       3       2       3
# 4:   4       2       2       3       1       2       2
```